How is 21/27 months of work calculated for Permanent Residency for Blue Card Holders in Germany?
I came to Germany on April 2022 under Fachkräfteeinwanderungsgesetz changes, as a skilled laborer in Tech with 3 years of qualifying experience. After the Blue Card changes, I applied for one and was given one on February 2024. I also have an A1 certificate from Goethe Institut. I have retained employment for the entire duration that I've lived here (May 2022 onwards).
I now want to apply for Permanent Residency (Niederlassungserlaubnis), but I'm not sure I qualify. I have worked in Germany for 31+ months in a skilled job that would qualify under today's EU Blue Card rules, but didn't for a large portion of the duration that I was working those jobs.

I have looked online, and the sites of big cities do not seem to answer this question:
https://stadt.muenchen.de/service/info/hauptabteilung-ii-buergerangelegenheiten/1080810/

Sie haben eine qualifizierte Beschäftigung von mindestens 33 Monaten und einfache Kenntnisse der deutschen Sprache (A1).

does not go into what a "qualifizierte Beschäftigung" is, and still quotes the old 33 month number. If relevant, I'd be applying for PR in Munich.
https://welcome.hamburg.de/einreise-und-aufenthalt/aufenthaltserlaubnisse/niederlassungerlaubnis-416776

Wenn Sie eine Blaue Karte EU besitzen und über einfache Deutschkenntnisse (A1) verfügen, können Sie bereits nach 27 Monaten qualifizierter Beschäftigung die Niederlassungserlaubnis beantragen.

does not go into what a "qualifizierter Beschäftigung" is.
https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326556/

Wenn Sie einfache Deutsch-Kenntnisse haben, müssen Sie seit mindestens 27 Monaten eine Beschäftigung ausüben. Diese Beschäftigung muss die Anforderungen für die Erteilung einer Blauen Karte EU erfüllen.

does not go into if they must've historically fulfilled the blue card requirements, or if they only need to fulfill it right now.

and as for the law:
https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__18c.html

(2) Abweichend von Absatz 1 ist dem Inhaber einer Blauen Karte EU eine Niederlassungserlaubnis zu erteilen, wenn er mindestens 27 Monate eine Beschäftigung nach § 18g ausgeübt hat und für diesen Zeitraum Pflichtbeiträge oder freiwillige Beiträge zur gesetzlichen Rentenversicherung geleistet hat oder Aufwendungen für einen Anspruch auf vergleichbare Leistungen einer Versicherungs- oder Versorgungseinrichtung oder eines Versicherungsunternehmens nachweist und die Voraussetzungen des § 9 Absatz 2 Satz 1 Nummer 2 und 4 bis 6, 8 und 9 vorliegen und er über einfache Kenntnisse der deutschen Sprache verfügt. § 9 Absatz 2 Satz 2 bis 4 und 6 gilt entsprechend. Die Frist nach Satz 1 verkürzt sich auf 21 Monate, wenn der Ausländer über ausreichende Kenntnisse der deutschen Sprache verfügt.

Again, my employment, current and historic, qualifies under §18g, but did not when I was working for ~1.5 years of it.

I have also seen this question, but it does not answer the question of what happens if the blue card requirements change during the course of one's employment (I'm not asking if it'll be counted from Feb 2024 onwards, I'm asking if it'll be counted from ~Nov 2023 onwards):
Is the 21 month period calculated from the Blue card application date or the issue date for Niederlassungserlaubnis?

So, how does the calculation work if the law changed in the middle? Do I qualify for permanent residency? Is my only option to try and find out the "hard" way?

As a personal note, having to apply in Munich does not make me the most confident. I changed employers at the start of the year, and even though I had 1.5+yrs of job experience in DE before that and almost two years at the point that I got my blue card, they still put the requirement on my blue card to report my job changes to them for the first year of my employment at current job. As far as I can tell, that law can be read in both ways, and Munich chose to read in the way that is unfavorable to me. I fear they may also feel the same about this.

Any specific concern or need to quit your job that makes you unwilling to wait for May 2025? Or you want to do this simply to secure your status as soon as possible?

@Relaxed the economy and industry is unstable, and being allowed to remain unemployed for longer would be useful.

Yes, definitely, I was just asking if there was a special concern about a potential 5-month delay that means it was essential for you to apply immediately. I imagine this could change the answer a bit.

@Relaxed my employer is likely going insolvent in 2 months. That doesn't encourage me to apply for a PR immediately, but it makes me paranoid about the state of startups these days, and I want to apply for PR as soon as I find a new job (or when I learn my employer will survive).


So, how does the calculation work if the law changed in the middle? Do I qualify for permanent residency? Is my only option to try and find out the "hard" way?

I don't have a solid answer on the interpretation of the phrase “Beschäftigung nach § 18g” but it seems to me that another option you have is simply applying after 36 months, in May 2025. Since you have already worked in Germany for 31 months, the difference isn't that great anymore.
If I understand your description correctly, your job(s) did in any case satisfy the requirements in §§ 18a, 18b, 18d or § 18g, even if they did not necessarily satisfy the requirements in § 18g (Blue Card). After 3 years, you will therefore fulfill the regular requirements for skilled workers in § 18c Absatz 1 Satz 1 without relying on the reduced Blue Card time frame. You would also require a higher-level German language certificate (B1).
This also means that even if you decide to apply immediately to “find out the hard way” and the decision is negative, you will still be able to apply again relatively soon, at least if you have a job.

I appreciate your answer, and I forgot that the 36 month option continues to exist. This is potentially useful for me and I'll give an upvote, but I'm hoping for an answer that also covers others in my situation that aren't so close to 36 months can get PR at 27 or 21 months, and that's what I plan to mark as answer.

@ave Yes, makes sense in light of our discussion, I was even thinking about deleting the answer, which doesn't really address your immediate problem of securing your status before your employer potentially becomes insolvant.

Oh, one catch with this: 36 month requires a B1 certificate, which I don't currently have. It'd be useful to mention it in your answer. I think I can get there til May.

@ave Done, thanks! Another concern is that I don't think you would be able to apply if you are out of a job come May, see § 18g Absatz 2. That's why I think the issue with your employer is a big one.

I think I'd have bigger issues if I don't get a job by May, especially if ABH gives me a shorter period to look for a job :) I'm hoping to find one long before then.

@ave In any case note that the language requirements for the 21-month threshold is the same (ausreichende Kenntnisse) as it is under the regular § 18c rules. It's only after 27 months that “einfache Kenntnisse” is enough (not an issue for you obviously since you have been working in Germany for 31 months).
